# How to do a process after finishing the fetch process?

Tags: sqlite, react-native, fetch

so I have a fetch method, inside that fetch I have Object function which will loop the data returned from the fetch and insert them into a local table/database.

but when the process has finished, I want to do a setState.
what I got, before the fetch finished, the setState has already been called.

```
fetch ( link, { 
            method : 'POST' ,
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'application/json' ,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json' ,
                'x-api-key' : api
            } ,
            body : JSON.stringify({
                "ent":
                {
                    "GetDataCode":"GRELIGION",
                    "AppId": APPID
                }
            })
        })
        .then ( response => response.json() )
        .then ( res => {

            db.transaction( ( tx ) => {
                tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM Religion')
            })

            Object.keys(JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal)).map( ( key ) => {
                db.transaction( ( tx ) => {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Religion VALUES (?,?)' , [ (JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal))[key].ID , (JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal))[key].Description ] , () => {
                        console.log('done')
                    } )
                })
            })

            this.setState({ // I want to call this after Object finished
                count : this.state.count + 1
            })
        })
```

please kindly correct me if I write something wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try this easy fix to see if the thats the last item to push in the database, once thats true, do the setState?
like `if(Object.keys(JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal)).length - 1 === index) { // dosomething as this the last action in the loop}`

```
fetch ( link, { 
            method : 'POST' ,
            headers : {
                'Accept' : 'application/json' ,
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json' ,
                'x-api-key' : api
            } ,
            body : JSON.stringify({
                "ent":
                {
                    "GetDataCode":"GRELIGION",
                    "AppId": APPID
                }
            })
        })
        .then ( response => response.json() )
        .then ( res => {

            db.transaction( ( tx ) => {
                tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM Religion')
            })

            Object.keys(JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal)).map( ( key, index ) => {
                db.transaction( ( tx ) => {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Religion VALUES (?,?)' , [ (JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal))[key].ID , (JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal))[key].Description ] , () => {
                        console.log('done');
                        if(Object.keys(JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal)).length - 1 === index) {
                        this.setState({ // I want to call this after Object finished
                          count : this.state.count + 1
                        })
    }
                    })
                })
            })
        })
```

Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: where is the 'index' come from?

Comment: Opps, sorry, forgot that to add, `Object.keys(JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal)).map( ( key, index ) =>`

Comment: is it need to write Object.keys(JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal)).length?
or is it just JSON.parse(res.GetDataResult.RetVal).length?

Comment: As long somehow you are getting the length of the data.

Comment: oh it works bro!! thanks for your help. i read about async await, but i don't know yet how to implement it. so this trick really helps me..

Answer (score 0):

You basically forgot to check whether the fetch request is succesful. Add a **catch()** and an **if** to check for an appropriate status code.

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server side, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful fetch() would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the Response.ok property has a value of true. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Your code should look something like this:

```
fetch('link', ...).then(function(response) {
  if(response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
}).then(function(res) { 
  ...;
  this.setState(...);
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ', error.message);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response, yeah I know that.
but here, what i focus on is not about the network, i focus on how to do the process after an Object process

Comment: Your setState is placed correctly and can't be called before the fetch is finished. The request may fails and you don't check for that...